# Atomic density derivative with respect to nuclear coordinates transformed to all space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-chemistry

Please show that the derivative of some atomic density $\rho_{I}$ with respect to its nuclear coordinate $R_{I}$ can be expressed in terms of its electronic coordinate $|\textbf{r - R}_I|$

$ \frac{\partial \rho_{I}(|\textbf{r - R}_I|)}{\partial R_{I}} =  \frac{\partial  \rho_{I}(|\textbf{r - R}_I|)}{\partial |\textbf{r}-\textbf{R}_{I}|} \frac{\textbf{r - R}_I}{|\textbf{r - R}_I|}$

Also, how would we then extend this to consider the derivative with respect to a component of the nuclear coordinate e.g. $R_{Ix}$?

$ \frac{\partial \rho_{I}(|\textbf{r - R}_I|)}{\partial R_{Ix}} =  ?$

Comment: Isn't this just an application of the chain rule?

Comment: @probably_someone Is it? If so that would be great. Apologies, I am not as strong mathematically as I would like. Could you please show an example?

Comment: @probably_someone I am afraid that I don't understand how the chain rule would apply here, if you have some insight that would be fantastic.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial \rho(|r-R_I|)}{\partial R_I}=\frac{\partial\rho(|r-R_I|)}{\partial|r-R_I|}\cdot\frac{\partial|r-R_I|}{\partial R_I}$$

Comment: @Tyberius Thanks! However I'm not sure I quite follow how $\frac{\partial|r-R_I|}{\partial R_I} = \frac{\textbf{r - R}_I}{|\textbf{r - R}_I|}$

Comment: Well $\frac{\partial|a-x|}{\partial x}=\frac{x-a}{|a-x|}$. So I guess either I or the source you got your equation from lost a sign somewhere.

Comment: @Tyberius  Thanks for your help! How would you go about taking the derivative with respect to a component of the nuclear coordinate (e.g if I was using it to calculate a Cartesian force)? Does this just become $\frac{\partial \rho_{I}(|\textbf{r - R}_I|)}{\partial R_{Ix}} =
     -\frac{R_{Ix}}{R_{I}}
    \frac{\partial  \rho_{I}(|\textbf{r - R}_I|)}{\partial |\textbf{r}_{}-\textbf{R}_{}|}
    \frac{\textbf{r}_{}-\textbf{R}_{I}}{|\textbf{r}_{}-\textbf{R}_{I}|}$?